# Rails 3 route question: use top level url based on model name not id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am writing a rails 3 application and want to change an existing route that goes like:

domain.com/tapes/2

to that:

domain.com/tapename

i.e., instead of fetching the default route based on resource 'tapes' id, I want the app to match any string 'tapename' to the show page of the corresponding record.

Could you please point me to the right direction?
Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new `match` statement as the **last** route in your `routes.rb` file (if you put it earlier, it'll be matched before other resources; and of course, make sure your `shows` resource is listed before the `match` statement):

```
resources :shows
match "/:id" => "tapes#show"
```